# Read file line by line in sourced bash script within heredoc

Tags: bash

I have two scripts. Script A includes script B and calls a function in script B.

The setup looks like this:

**Test file - ~/file.txt**

```
one==1.0.0
two==2.0.0
three==3.0.0
four==4.0.0
```

**Script A - ~/script_a.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
source script_b.sh
func_one
```

**Script B - ~/script_b.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
# Note: don't forget to change the spaces to tabs else heredoc won't work
my_user=$USER
func_two() {
    # Here, I need run everything in the heredoc as user $my_user
    sudo su - $my_user -s /bin/bash <<- EOF            
        while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]];
        do
            # **This is the problem line**
            # I can confirm that all the lines are being 
            #  read but echo displays nothing
            echo "$line"
            # The line below will be printed 4 times as there are 4 lines in the file of interest
            echo "Test"
        done < "/home/$my_user/file.txt"
    EOF
}

func_one() {
    func_two
}
```

**To run**

```
cd ~
bash script_a.sh
```

**Question:** Why is the line `echo "$line"` not producing any output?

Comment: How do you confirm all lines are read?

Comment: If you add the line `echo test` above the line you are worried about do you get any output?

Comment: @iBug I `echo` a simple text along the one I want there and it gets printed the same number of times as there are lines in the file.

Comment: @jwpfox For `echo "test"`, `test` gets printed the same number of times as there are lines in the file of interest.

Comment: Can you make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can test with? Something that doesn't require "miniconda", whatever that is? If you keep removing complexity from the script, at what point does it behave as you expect?

Comment: @ghoti Couldn't quickly find an online bash tester that allows me to upload files or create multiple files but I changed the question into something that can dropped in your home folder. Hope that helps.

Comment: @jwpfox See [this example](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#CA-47120ef7c8534fbb8d04287560707aee3db999b5_1) and the others in that paragraph.

Comment: Sorry i am obviously not making my point well based on the responses. I’ll delete my comments to reduce the confusion I am causing. My bad  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that bash is substituting `$line` with its value (nothing) before it gets passed to su. Escaping the dollar sign should fix it. So `$line` should be changed to `\$line` in both places in script_b.sh.